# Intersection of set of upper and lower triangular matrices is the set of diagonal matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I want to prove that $\mathbb{F}_U(n,n)\cap\mathbb{F}_L(n,n)=\mathbb{F}_D(n,n)$.

This is very obvious to me when I think of these as matrices, but I want to rigorously prove this. I just learned about direct sums, so I know that $\mathbb{F}_U(n,n) +\mathbb{F}_L(n,n)\neq \mathbb{F}_U(n,n) \oplus\mathbb{F}_L(n,n)$ since $\mathbb{F}_U(n,n) \cap\mathbb{F}_L(n,n)\neq\{0\}$, but cannot see how/if I can use this to prove the statement.

Comment: I think the use of direct sums is inapt. If a matrix is both upper and lower triangular, what can you say about its off-diagonal entries?

Comment: @hardmath I can say the intersection has all non diagonals must be 0, but how would I be able to rigorously show this for some arbitrary fields? Intuitively, it is trivial, but I cannot extend this intuition to a rigorous proof.

Comment: You would use the definition (if you know it) of upper triangular matrix and lower triangular matrix "for some arbitrary field".  I'd guess you want to use the same definition in terms of entries that are zero.

Comment: @hardmath I was wondering if you might have a definition in terms of fields I could use? I haven't seen one in terms of fields.

Comment: $M \in \mathbb{F}_U(n,n)$ if for all $1 \leq i,j \leq n$, $M_{i,j} \in \mathbb{F}$ and when $ j < i$ $M_{i,j} = 0$.

Comment: @Rammus thanks a lot, I was having a lot of trouble in finding a neat way to express upper and lower triangular matrices, but this is perfect